# android recyclerview adapter progressbar not show

Tags: android

Refresh the `progress bar` multiple times not to show!
I am refreshing the data. This progress is not accurate. What I want is to show progress correctly every time I refresh.

Refresh the `progress bar` multiple times not to show!
I am refreshing the data. This progress is not accurate. What I want is to show progress correctly every time I refresh.

[image]

@[demo](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1ge3fBhT)

> activity

```
package com.hjyt.youmi.testdemo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androi

d.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private Button mBtn;

    private List<String> mDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mDataList.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_notify);
        mBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_notify:
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
        }
    }

    class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ProgressViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public ProgressViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_progress_layout, parent, false);
            return new ProgressViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ProgressViewHolder holder, int position) {

            setColors(holder.progressBar, Color.WHITE, Color.RED);
            java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
            holder.progressBar.setProgress(r.nextInt(100));

            holder.textView.setText("position: " + position + "\n progress: " + holder.progressBar.getProgress());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDataList.size();
        }

        private void setColors(ProgressBar progressBar, int backgroundColor, int progressColor) {
            //Background
            ClipDrawable bgClipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(new ColorDrawable(backgroundColor), Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
            bgClipDrawable.setLevel(10000);
            //Progress
            ClipDrawable progressClip = new ClipDrawable(new ColorDrawable(progressColor), Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
            //Setup LayerDrawable and assign to progressBar
            Drawable[] progressDrawables = {bgClipDrawable, progressClip, progressClip};
            LayerDrawable progressLayerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(progressDrawables);
            progressLayerDrawable.setId(0, android.R.id.background);
            progressLayerDrawable.setId(1, android.R.id.secondaryProgress);
            progressLayerDrawable.setId(2, android.R.id.progress);

            progressBar.setProgressDrawable(progressLayerDrawable);
        }

        class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            ProgressBar progressBar;

            TextView textView;

            ProgressViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
                textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hjyt.youmi.testdemo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_notify"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_notify"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="更新数据"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> adapter xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_desc"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progress"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved it myself and I don't need a progressbar to use a View and backgroud.

```
private void setColors(View viewBg, View view, int progressColor, int progress) {
            int width = viewBg.getWidth();
            int progress1 = width / 100;

            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = progress1 * progress;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);

            view.setBackgroundColor(progressColor);
        }
```

Comment: This is not using a ProgressBar - as the original question was v- this is hackish-ly creating a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below methods to show and hide progress bar :

```
 public static void showProgress(String message, Context context, boolean cancellable) {
        if (context == null)
            return;

        if (checkProgressOpen())
            return;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage(message == null ? "Please wait..." : (message));
        dialog.setCancelable(cancellable);
        try {
            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // catch exception for activity paused and dialog is going to be
            // show.
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkProgressOpen() {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static void cancelProgress() {
        if (checkProgressOpen()) {
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            dialog = null;
        }
    }
```

put this code in utility file , and use it wherever you need it..you can pass your message in arguments also

Comment: What I want is that the progrssbar is not a progressDialog